# The assigned variable shows 'null' in the WhatsApp

Tags: apex, null, apex-variable

I have an error where the **deviceType** variable shows as **null** in the WhatsApp message. The queueable method is called depending on the selected email template to send and the relevant details should be gathered.

Here is the OutboundEmails code;

```
public class OutboundEmails {
    /*
    * @param: Email data sent to customer.
    * 
    * This method get the email subject & based on the subject will sent specific whatsapp message template.
    */
    public static void afterEmailSent(List<EmailMessage> emails) {
        String customerName;
        String customerPhoneNumberCountryCode;
        String customerPhoneNumber;
        String num; // will store either ticket number or invoice number, based on the chosen email template subject
        String deviceType;
        DateTime collectedDateValue = DateTime.now(); // value for test unit (was always null)
        String emailTemplate;
        String branchName;
        
        String collectedDate;
        String collectedTime;
        
        for(EmailMessage email : emails) {
            // Retrieve the email address of the recipient
            String emailAddress = email.ToAddress;
            // Retrieve the email subject
            String emailSubject = email.Subject;
            
            // loop through the customers records and retieve record contains same email address
            Contact[] contact = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone, Country_Code__c FROM Contact WHERE Email = :emailAddress];
            
            for(Contact con : contact) {
                customerName = con.Name;
                customerPhoneNumberCountryCode = con.Country_Code__c;
                customerPhoneNumber = con.Phone;
            }
            
            // concatenate country code with the phone number
            String concatenatedString = customerPhoneNumberCountryCode + customerPhoneNumber;
            customerPhoneNumber = concatenatedString;
            
            // if the subject contains hyphen then proceed else return
            String subject = '';
            if(emailSubject.contains('-')) {
                // Find the position of the hyphen
                Integer hyphenIndex = emailSubject.indexOf('-');
                
                // Check if hyphen is at the start of the string
                if (hyphenIndex > 0){
                    // Extract the text before the hyphen
                  subject = emailSubject.substring(0, hyphenIndex).trim(); 
                }
                
                // Extract the keyword before the colon and trim any whitespace
                String keyword = '';
                Integer colonIndex = emailSubject.indexOf(':');
                if(colonIndex != -1 && colonIndex > hyphenIndex + 1){
                    keyword = emailSubject.substring(hyphenIndex + 1, colonIndex).trim();
                } else if(colonIndex == -1 || colonIndex <= hyphenIndex + 1) 

          // Check if colon exists in the string
          if (colonIndex > -1) {
              // Extract the ticket number after the colon and trim any whitespace
              num = emailSubject.substring(colonIndex + 1).trim();
          }
               
   
                if(keyword.equals('Ticket')) {
                    // find the ticket record using the ticket number from email subject
                    Ticket__c[] ticket = [SELECT Id, Name, Apple_Watch_Types__c, iMac_Types__c, iPad_Types__c, iPhone_Types__c,
                                          iPod_Types__c, Mac_Mini_Types__c, Macbook_Types__c, Collected_Date__c, Branch_Name__c  FROM Ticket__c WHERE Name = :num];
                    
                    for(Ticket__c tic : ticket) {
                        try{
                        if(tic.Apple_Watch_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.Apple_Watch_Types__c;
                        if(tic.iMac_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.iMac_Types__c;
                        if(tic.iPad_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.iPad_Types__c;
                        if(tic.iPhone_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.iPhone_Types__c; 
                        if(tic.iPod_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.iPod_Types__c;
                        if(tic.Mac_Mini_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.Mac_Mini_Types__c;
                        if(tic.Macbook_Types__c != null) deviceType = tic.Macbook_Types__c;
                        if(tic.Collected_Date__c != null) collectedDateValue = tic.Collected_Date__c;
                        
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            System.debug('Error assigning deviceType: ' + e);
                        }
                        
                        
                        branchName = tic.Branch_Name__c;
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    if(collectedDateValue != null) {
                        // seperate the DateTime data type to date data type & Time data type individually
                        DateTime myDateTime = collectedDateValue;
                        Date myDate = myDateTime.date();
                        collectedDate = String.valueOf(myDate);
                        Time myTime = myDateTime.time();
                        collectedTime = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), myTime).format('hh:mm a'); // 12 hour format
                    }
                } 
                
                if(keyword.equals('Invoice')) {
                    // none
                }
                
                // check each email template subject value
                if(subject == 'Diagnostic Result') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Diagnostic Result';
                }
                
                if(subject == 'Approval for Replacement') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Approval for Replacement';
                }
                
                if(subject == 'Return') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Return';
                }
                
                if(subject == 'Congratulations') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Congratulations';
                }
                
                /*if(subject == 'Received Payment') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Received Payment';
                }*/
                
                if(subject == 'Resolved') {
                    emailTemplate = 'Resolved';
                }
            }
        }
        
        // after the for loop call the queueable method
        if(emailTemplate == 'Diagnostic Result') {
            // call SendDiagnResToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendDiagnResToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, num, deviceType));
            return;
        }
        
        if(emailTemplate == 'Approval for Replacement') {
            // call SendApprovRepToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendApprovRepToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, deviceType));
        } 
        
        if(emailTemplate == 'Return') {
            // call SendReturnToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendReturnToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, deviceType));
        }
        
        if(emailTemplate == 'Congratulations') {
            // call SendCongratsToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendCongratsToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, deviceType, branchName));
        }
        
        /*if(emailTemplate == 'Received Payment') {
            // call SendRecePaymentToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendRecePaymentToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, num));
        }*/
        
        if(emailTemplate == 'Resolved') { // special case
            // call SendResolvedToCustomerWhatsapp
            System.enqueueJob(new SendResolvedToCustomerWhatsapp(customerName, customerPhoneNumber, deviceType, collectedDate, collectedTime, branchName));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding *else if* and verifying if it is not null by assigning a text value for the **deviceType** variable.

Here is the code that I'm testing now which is the **Diagnostic Result email template** ;

```
public class SendDiagnResToCustomerWhatsapp implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public String customerName;
    public String customerPhoneNumber;
    public String ticketNumber;
    public String deviceType;
    //public String ticketIssue;
    //public String branchName;
    
    public SendDiagnResToCustomerWhatsapp(String customerName, String customerPhoneNumber, String ticketNumber, String deviceType) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.customerPhoneNumber = customerPhoneNumber;
        this.ticketNumber = ticketNumber;
        this.deviceType = deviceType;
        //this.ticketIssue = ticketIssue;
        //this.branchName = branchName;
    }
    
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        String message = 'Dear ' + customerName + ',' + '\\n' + 'We have completed the diagnostic process for your ' + deviceType + '.'
            + ' The detailed results have been sent to your registered email address. Please check your inbox or spam folder for the report. If you have any questions or need further assistance, feel free to reach out to our support team.' + '\\n'
            + 'Thank you.';
        String messageQuoted = '"' + message + '"';
        
        String customerPhoneNumberQuoted = '"' + customerPhoneNumber + '"';
        
        System.debug('send diagnostic results to whatsapp');
        System.debug('TESTING DEVICETYPE ' + deviceType);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://wa-toolbox.web.app/webhooks/5BNTAXR8U');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        
        // the body will contain the payload of the message
        request.setBody('{"action": "send-message", "type": "text", "content":' + messageQuoted + ', "phone":' + customerPhoneNumberQuoted + '}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        
        // Parse the JSON response
        if(response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            // if post request failed
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

The WhatsApp text message image;
[image]

Any ideas to get this solved would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE! Given that the other properties are being correctly displayed it might be that you're not entering the if-clause that populates deviceType. I'd suggest you debug the `for(Ticket__c tic : ticket)` loop to assure you're entering there, and if so then check the values of each `*-_Types__c` field to understand if there is where the value is missing to be populated.

Comment: @user1067017 Thank you for the reply I'll try debugging the line `for(Ticket__c tic : ticket)` , it's quite weird because it was working for months with no errors and suddenly an error occurred.